# Responsive background image in angular 5 for both desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a background image to the app.component.html file in angular 5. The issues the background image is not covering the full height of the mobile devices. In desktop it is working fine.

Below is my app.component.css file

```
.main-body {
    height: stretch;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

below is my app.component.html file

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <img src="{{agtContentService.logoUrl}}" width={{agtContentService.logoWidth}} height="{{agtContentService.logoHeight}}">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" font-size="120%">
      <li><h4>{{agtContentService.title}}<br>
        <small>{{agtContentService.subtitle}}</small>
      </h4></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid main-body" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 100%), url('+agtContentService.backgroundUrl+')'}">
    <br><br><br>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In the mobile view, when I scroll down the background is white and the background image is not covering the full height. Any help? I have tried most of the solutions I could find in internet and still couldn't get it to work. Can anyone know the right way to fix this problem.

And also when I use below css code, the mobile view works fine but then the desktop view shows white background in the area which the background image is not covering

```
.main-body {
    /* height: stretch; */
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: please share a working demo.

Comment: try just .main-body {
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}